# How to create an infinite Stream<E> out of an Iterator<E>?

Tags: java, iterator, java-8, java-stream

Looking at the following class I've made:

```
public class FibonacciSupplier implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private final IntPredicate hasNextPredicate;

    private int beforePrevious = 0;
    private int previous = 1;

    private FibonacciSupplier(final IntPredicate hasNextPredicate) {
        this.hasNextPredicate = hasNextPredicate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNextPredicate.test(previous);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        int result = beforePrevious + previous;
        beforePrevious = previous;
        previous = result;
        return result;
    }

    public static FibonacciSupplier infinite() {
        return new FibonacciSupplier(i -> true);
    }

    public static FibonacciSupplier finite(final IntPredicate predicate) {
        return new FibonacciSupplier(predicate);
    }
}
```

And the usage of it in:

```
public class Problem2 extends Problem<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        result = toList(FibonacciSupplier.finite(i -> (i <= 4_000_000)))
                .stream()
                .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
                .mapToInt(i -> i)
                .sum();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Problem 2";
    }

    private static <E> List<E> toList(final Iterator<E> iterator) {
        List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            list.add(iterator.next());
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

How would I be able to create an **infinite** `Stream<E>`?

If I were to use `Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = toList(FibonacciSupplier.infinite()).stream()`, I would, possibly surprisingly, never get an infinite stream.
Instead the code would loop forever in the creation of the `list` in an underlying method.

This so far is purely theoretical, but I can definately understand the need for it if I would want to first skip the first x numbers from an infinite stream, and then limit it by the last y numbers, something like:

```
int x = MAGIC_NUMBER_X;
int y = MAGIC_NUMBER_y;
int sum = toList(FibonacciSupplier.infinite())
    .stream()
    .skip(x)
    .limit(y)
    .mapToInt(i -> i)
    .sum();
```

The code would not ever return a result, how should it be done?

Comment: Is what you're asking how to write a generator using the new Java 8 features?

Comment: @chrylis It's not necessarily what I'm asking, but it could very well be a very good and correct answer.

Comment: I'm trying to clarify whether what you mean by "infinite Stream" is the same as the generator pattern.

Comment: @chrylis Ah yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 28):

Your mistake is to think that you need an `Iterator` or a `Collection` to create a `Stream`. For creating an infinite stream, a single method providing one value after another is enough. So for your class `FibonacciSupplier` the simplest use is:

```
IntStream s=IntStream.generate(FibonacciSupplier.infinite()::next);
```

or, if you prefer boxed values:

```
Stream<Integer> s=Stream.generate(FibonacciSupplier.infinite()::next);
```

Note that in this case the method does not have to be named `next` nor fulfill the `Iterator` interface. But it doesn’t matter if it does as with your class. Further, as we just told the stream to use the `next` method as a `Supplier`, the `hasNext` method will never be called. It’s just infinite.

Creating a finite stream using your `Iterator` is a bit more complicated:

```
Stream<Integer> s=StreamSupport.stream(
  Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
    FibonacciSupplier.finite(intPredicate), Spliterator.ORDERED),
  false);
```

In this case if you want a finite `IntStream` with unboxed `int` values your `FibonacciSupplier` should implement `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt`.

Comment: How FibonacciSupplier can supply anything, not getting the index as input parameter anywhere?

Comment: @Gangnus: look at the question to see, how the `FibonacciSupplier` works. It’s iterative, the method `next` has to be called as many times as needed and the stream will do exactly that.

Comment: But for counting next, I have to sum two previous numbers. Where and how can I get them in supplier? You have forgotten to write the more interesting or difficult part of the answer.

Comment: @Gangnus: *Again*, the working supplier is already given in the question. There is nothing to discuss about it. The question was, how to create a stream out of it, and this answer is, well, answering the question, nothing more. If you have a different question, you can always [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Terribly sorry, I read only the answer and haven't seen the supplier.

Comment: The finite version in Java 9: `[Int]Stream.generate(FibonacciSupplier.infinite()::next).takeWhile(intPredicate)`.

Answer (score 18):

In Java 8 there are no *public, concrete classes* implementing the interface [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). However, there are some *static factory methods*. One of the most important is [StreamSupport.stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-). In particular, it is used in the *default method* [Collection.stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) –inherited by most collection classes:

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
}
```

The default implementation of this method creates a [Spliterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) by invoking `spliterator()`, and passes the created object to the factory method. *Spliterator* is a new interface introduced with Java 8 to support *parallel streams*. It is similar to *Iterator*, but in contrast to the latter, a *Spliterator* can be divided into parts, that can be processed independently. See [Spliterator.trySplit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#trySplit--) for details.

The *default method* [Iterable.spliterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#spliterator--) was also added in Java 8, so that every *Iterable* class automatically supports *Spliterators*. The implementation looks as follows:

```
default Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
    return Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator(), 0);
}
```

The method creates the *Spliterator* from an arbitrary *Iterator*. If you combine these two steps, you can create a *Stream* from an arbitrary *Iterator*:

```
<T> Stream<T> stream(Iterator<T> iterator) {
    Spliterator<T> spliterator
        = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0);
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
}
```

---

To get an impression of *Spliterators*, here is a very simple example without using collections. The following class implements *Spliterator* to iterate over a half-open interval of integers:

```
public final class IntRange implements Spliterator.OfInt {
    private int first, last;
    public IntRange(int first, int last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }
    public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
        if (first < last) {
            action.accept(first++);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public OfInt trySplit() {
        int size = last - first;
        if (size >= 10) {
            int temp = first;
            first += size / 2;
            return new IntRange(temp, first);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public long estimateSize() {
        return Math.max(last - first, 0);
    }
    public int characteristics() {
        return ORDERED | DISTINCT | SIZED | NONNULL
            | IMMUTABLE | CONCURRENT | SUBSIZED;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain a bit more what it does exactly? I understand almost all concepts of Java 8, but `Spliterator`s remain tricky to grasp.

Comment: @skiwi Under the hood, streams can be split up for parallel processing on multi-core systems. Spliterators are a a kind of iterators that can be split up too for this purpose. They're incompatible with classic iterators, so for backwards compatibility they just added the new versions alongside the old ones and gave them a weird name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the low level stream support primitives and the `Spliterators` library to make a stream out of an `Iterator`.

The last parameter to `StreamSupport.stream()` says that the stream is not parallel. Be sure to let it like that because your Fibonacci iterator depends on previous iterations.

```
return StreamSupport.stream( Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize( new Iterator<Node>()
{
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        // to implement
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public ContentVersion next()
    {
        // to implement
        return ...;
    }
}, Spliterator.ORDERED ), false );
```

Answer (score 0):

To add another answer, perhaps AbstractSpliterator is a better choice, especially given the example code. Generate is inflexible as there is no [good] way to give a stop condition except by using limit. Limit only accepts a number of items rather than a predicate, so we have to know how many items we want to generate - which might not be possible, and what if the generator is a black box passed to us?

AbstractSpliterator is a halfway house between having to write a whole spliterator, and using Iterator/Iterable. AbstractSpliterator lacks just the tryAdvance method where we first check our predicate for being done, and if not pass the generated value to an action. Here's an example of a Fibonacci sequence using AbstractIntSpliterator:

```
public class Fibonacci {
    private static class FibonacciGenerator extends Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator
    {
        private IntPredicate hasNextPredicate;
        private int beforePrevious = 0;
        private int previous = 0;

        protected FibonacciGenerator(IntPredicate hasNextPredicate)
        {
            super(Long.MAX_VALUE, 0);
            this.hasNextPredicate = hasNextPredicate;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action)
        {
            if (action == null)
            {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }

            int next = Math.max(1, beforePrevious + previous);
            beforePrevious = previous;
            previous = next;

            if (!hasNextPredicate.test(next))
            {
                return false;
            }

            action.accept(next);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Integer> action)
        {
            if (action == null)
            {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }

            int next = Math.max(1, beforePrevious + previous);
            beforePrevious = previous;
            previous = next;

            if (!hasNextPredicate.test(next))
            {
                return false;
            }

            action.accept(next);

            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Stream<Integer> infiniteStream = StreamSupport.stream(
                new FibonacciGenerator(i -> true), false);

        Stream<Integer> finiteStream = StreamSupport.stream(
                new FibonacciGenerator(i -> i < 100), false);

        // Print with a side-effect for the demo
        infiniteStream.limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
        finiteStream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

For more details I've covered generators in Java 8 in my blog http://thecannycoder.wordpress.com/