# Using an event listener as Java 8 Stream source

Tags: java, java-8, future, java-stream

### Quick-n-Dirty

Is it possible to refactor a traditional event listener into a Java 8 Stream, such that listener events become the stream source?

#### Long Story

A client submits an arbitrary job, then listens for results:

```
Client client = new JobClient()
client.addTaskListener(this)
client.submitJobAsync( new MultiTaskJob())  //returns void, important (see below)

public void onTaskResult(TaskResult result){
  if(result.isLastResult())
    aggregateJobResults(result)
  else
    processResult(result)
}
```

#### Problem

For any job submitted, the client receives *n* results, but it doesn't know how many results it will receive (it uses `isLastResult()` to determine when to stop and aggregate).

#### Goal

I want to refactor the listener into a "supplier", or something similiar, such that `onTaskResult()` is the stream source:

```
Supplier<TaskResult> taskResultSupplier = 
    () -> Stream.of( .. )   //onTaskResult() feeds this
            .map(result -> {
               if(result.isLastResult())
                 //logic here
             });
```

Something like that; if I can do it without the client knowing how many results to expect, I'm golden; right now, `submitJobAsync()` returns void, I'd like to keep it that way, but I'm open to options as well...

#### Alternatives

After reading up on [CompletableFutures](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-completablefuture-in-action.html) by Tomasz Nurkiewicz for a similar scenario, an alternate option exists, assuming a minor change to the client:

```
List<CompletableFuture<TaskResult>> taskFutures = 
  client.submitJobAsync( new MultiTaskJob())
```

Here, the client gets a list of `CompletableFutures<TaskResult>`, so we need to collect the results of the futures when they complete:

```
//processes all task result futures 
List<TaskResult> = taskFutures.stream()
  .map(taskResult ->
     taskResult.thenApply(this::processResult))
  .collect(Collectors.<TaskResult>toList());
```

The article also illustrates using `CompletableFuture.allOf(..)` to perform final processing but only after *all* futures complete (it's pretty slick); that's where aggregation would occur in my case. No code to show for that here, though the article does a great job explaining it (I'm a total n00b with streams, though if I get it working I'll post the code:-D )

Comment: You can make this work, but you won't be happy with the result.  Streams is just not a reactive framework; you can force it into being one, but then you'll see the ways in which it just wasn't designed as one.  Try RxJava, I think its a better match for the problem you are solving.

Comment: A fundamental design assumption about streams is that the source data is merely computation-cycles away, either generated by a function, or sitting in a collection.  When the data can arrive asynchronously, you have to deal with things like cancellation, backpressure, etc... which Streams wasn't built for.  It was built for fast, possibly-parallel aggregate operations on near-to-memory data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to construct a Stream around your TaskResults. See this example:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

/**
 * Created for http://stackoverflow.com/q/27670421/1266906.
 */
public class AsyncToStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Unbuffered Test:");
        AsyncTaskResultIterator<TaskResult> taskListener1 = new AsyncTaskResultIterator<>();
        new TaskResultGenerator(taskListener1, 5).start();
        taskListener1.unbufferedStream().forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("Buffered Test:");
        AsyncTaskResultIterator<TaskResult> taskListener2 = new AsyncTaskResultIterator<>();
        new TaskResultGenerator(taskListener2, 5).start();
        taskListener2.bufferedStream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    /**
     * This class wraps a sequence of TaskResults into an iterator upto the first TaskResult where {@code }isLastResult()} returns {@code true}
     */
    public static class AsyncTaskResultIterator<T extends TaskResult> implements Iterator<T>, TaskListener<T> {

        /**
         * This acts as an asynchronous buffer so we can easily wait for the next TaskResult
         */
        private final BlockingQueue<T> blockingQueue;
        /**
         * Becomes {@code true} once {@code TaskResult.isLastResult()} is received
         */
        private       boolean          ended;

        public AsyncTaskResultIterator() {
            blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        }

        /**
         * Waits on a new TaskResult and returns it as long as the previous TaskResult did not specify {@code isLastResult()}. Afterwards no more elements can be retrieved.
         */
        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (ended) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            } else {
                try {
                    T next = blockingQueue.take();
                    ended = next.isLastResult();
                    return next;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not retrieve next value", e);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !ended;
        }

        /**
         * Enqueue another TaskResult for retrieval
         */
        @Override
        public void onTaskResult(T result) {
            if (ended) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Already received a TaskResult with isLastResult() == true");
            }
            try {
                blockingQueue.put(result);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not enqueue next value", e);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Builds a Stream that acts upon the results just when they become available
         */
        public Stream<T> unbufferedStream() {
            Spliterator<T> spliterator = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(this, 0);
            return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
        }

        /**
         * Buffers all results and builds a Stream around the results
         */
        public Stream<T> bufferedStream() {
            Stream.Builder<T> builder = Stream.builder();
            this.forEachRemaining(builder);
            return builder.build();
        }
    }

    public static class TaskResultImpl implements TaskResult {
        private boolean lastResult;
        private String  name;

        public TaskResultImpl(boolean lastResult, String name) {
            this.lastResult = lastResult;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "TaskResultImpl{" +
                    "lastResult=" + lastResult +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastResult() {
            return lastResult;
        }
    }

    public static interface TaskListener<T extends TaskResult> {
        public void onTaskResult(T result);
    }

    public static interface TaskResult {
        boolean isLastResult();
    }

    private static class TaskResultGenerator extends Thread {
        private final TaskListener<TaskResult> taskListener;
        private final int                      count;

        public TaskResultGenerator(TaskListener<TaskResult> taskListener, int count) {
            this.taskListener = taskListener;
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                    taskListener.onTaskResult(new TaskResultImpl(false, String.valueOf(i)));
                }
                Thread.sleep(200);
                taskListener.onTaskResult(new TaskResultImpl(true, String.valueOf(count)));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You did not provide your TaskResult and TaskListener-definitions so I made up my own. AsyncTaskResultIterator will work only for single TaskResult-sequences. If no TaskResult with `isLastResult() == true` is supplied `next()` and therefore also the unbuffered Stream and the buffered Stream generation will wait endlessly.

Comment: very interesting, and pretty much what I was looking for: Is `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize()` necessary? Assuming `AsyncTaskResultIterator` was also a `Supplier`, would this also work?  `Stream.generate(taskResultSupplier::next())`, from http://stackoverflow.com/q/21956515/791406

Comment: I looked into Supplier and you can use it. You just will not have an opportunity to end your Stream. Just as if you would always return true from hasNext()

Answer (score 1):

As Brian Goetz says, why don't you give RxJava a try?

Have a look at takeWhile (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Conditional-and-Boolean-Operators#takewhile) and map (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#map).